# Compilar y ejecutar proyecto Java desde terminal da No se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

Tags: java, terminal, compilar

estoy intentando compilar y ejecutar un proyecto Java desde la terminal de Windows, tengo una carpeta `.\lib` con varios `.jar`

Para compilar utilizo el siguiente comando:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 -d .\bin -cp .\src .\src\partida\Partido.java
```

Me compila sin errores
Pero me da error al ejecutarlo con la siguiente instrucción:

```
java -cp .\bin .\Partida\Partido**
```

Me da el error:

> No se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal .\Partido.java

Tengo también en la carpeta .\lib unos .jar, pero no se como pasar esto al classpath en la compilación, he probado con esto pero no funciona;

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 -d .\bin -cp .\src \lib .\src\partida\Partido.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo al ejecutar desde la terminal de windows es primero descargar el JDK desde la pagina de Oracle Una vez que lo hayas bajado e instalado correctamente, procede a buscar la ruta de instalación por ejemplo:
    1 | C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin

Equipo -> Click derecho -> Propiedades -> Configuración Avanzada del Sistema -> [Pestaña] Opciones Avanzadas -> Variables de Entorno
Buscamos en el cuadro mostrado la variable de nombre Path, presionamos Editar, en el cuadro mostrado, nos vamos hasta el final del texto que ya está escrito y agregamos lo siguiente sin las comillas:
";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;"

Una vez que hayamos añadido la ruta, presionamos OK, luego nuevamente OK e iniciamos una consola (cmd) y escribimos javac, nos debería salir algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues compilas tu programa buscando la ruta de tu carpeta e indicando el nombre del archivo tal y como esta escrito no olvidar poner que son.java o depende del codigo que quieres correr
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que `src\partida\Partido.java` esta en el package partida.

Y lo compilas con:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 -d .\bin -cp .\src .\src\partida\Partido.java
```

Entonces para ejecutarlo, debes especificar el nombre de clase completo:

```
java -cp bin partido.Partido
```